# Chef - Prevent execution of multiple resources

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, recipe

Let's say I have 3 `execute` resources *'Create users'*, *'Install client'* and *'Verify client'*.

How can I prevent execution of all those resources if one condition is satisfied ?

Something like:

```
block 'Manage client' do 
    execute 'Create users' do
      cwd      scripts_path
      command  './installClient.sh -create_users'
    end
    execute 'Install client' do
      cwd      scripts_path
      command  '/installClient.sh -installClient'
    end
    execute 'Verify client' do
      cwd      scripts_path
      command  './installClient.sh -verifyClient'
    end
    not_if { ::File.exists?('/tmp/client_configured_success') }
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a normal `if/unless` conditional like in any other Ruby code.

```
unless File.exist?('/tmp/client_configured_success')
    execute 'Create users' do
      cwd      scripts_path
      command  './installClient.sh -create_users'
    end
    execute 'Install client' do
      cwd      scripts_path
      command  '/installClient.sh -installClient'
    end
    execute 'Verify client' do
      cwd      scripts_path
      command  './installClient.sh -verifyClient'
    end
end
```

Comment: And yes, foodcritic will complain about this. Foodcritic is wrong.